# How to convert stream into pdf or display stream in pdf format using php or javascript?

Tags: php, pdf, stream

How to convert stream into pdf or display stream as pdf on webpage using php or javascript?

Sample stream:

```
Â

13 0 obj
&lt;&lt;
  /Length 66/Filter/FlateDecode
&gt;&gt; stream
[some binary data]

endstream
endobj";
```

I will be thankful if any body can help

Comment: Thanks Laura for correcting the question.  Anybody please help.

Answer (score 0):

The PDF file format is not at all trivial and even a simple one typically onsists of several objects.  It appears your stream has syntax like an excerpt from a pdf, but a bit different.  How are you encountering such streams?

Comment: Hi JosephA. I get this stream from an api. I saved it in db. My goal is to display it on webpage using php or javascript. Please help, how to do this

Comment: I'm afraid we simply need more context to answer that question, what API are you speaking of?  If the answer is an API that is _supposed_ to provide you with a _complete_, _valid_ PDF then what you have supplied is not full, correct PDF syntax and you should find any PDF viewer not capable of opening it if you saved the content to disk.  If not, please explain further.